# Can xposed framework impact system performance and battery?

Tags: xposed-framework

I've installed [Xposed framework](http://repo.xposed.info) and Sense 5 Toolbox module on my HTC One X and doubt that if it is draining my battery and causing the system to slow.

I've checked with [Watchdog](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.zomut.watchdoglite) and Setting-Apps-Running but seems like there is no background service running. What I thought was there must be service monitoring the user actions but it wasn't.

I would be very appreciate if somebody answer the question from title and explain how xposed actually work on Android.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Xposed isn't a separate service: instead, it's a wrapper in every process, which replaces some built-in functions from the Android framework.

For this reason, it's very likely that it'll have some effect on system performance, but exactly what effect depends on the particular modules. For example, it would be possible (but unlikely) for a module to replace a built-in function that's called frequently with a different version that runs more slowly and uses more battery (and probably even gives the wrong answer at the end).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you think changing the button behavior like long power button for flashlight, long back for force kill process and long home press for lock screen can impact performance and drain battery performance?

Comment: Like any program's performance, it will depend not on what the module does, but how it was written. You can make a guess by looking at the source code, but only measuring on a real device will tell you for sure.

Comment: So, no matter the mod is re-compiled into system apk or using xposed module, there is no difference if code is written well?

Comment: In general, yes. Xposed is just a way of modifying the framework APK at runtime.

Comment: I am using 14 modules and despite this I never experience lagging or battery draining. But behind this positive experience is my hard work in careful selection just quality modules which fulfill my needs. With Xposed Framework can one be happy with just stock ROM.